# Temporarily cap PEX pipe while laying new flooring?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pex

I am remodeling a bathroom. We’re going to lay new tile and replace a vanity. This requires removing the toilet and old vanity. In order to remove the old vanity I need to cut the PEX piping attached to the shut off valves for the faucet.

I have PEX caps and cinch rings, do those hold well enough so I can turn the water back on for a few days until I can get the new vanity installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they should work fine.  Do you have the crimp tool?

Another option is to use a Sharkbite end cap.

Comment: Yes, I have the stainless steel cinch rings and caps.

Comment: @EMAW2008 - Well you have the cinch rings -- But the question asked was if you have a proper crimping tool for those cinch rings.